# Inserting a hyphen when string changes from alpha to numeric

Tags: performance, perl

Given a random alphanumeric string (A-Z0-9) between 1 to 10 characters long, I'd like to insert a hyphen when it changes from alpha to numeric, or numeric to alpha.

I have something that works now, but I'm sure it performs as awful as it looks. I know there's a better way to handle this, but someone in the office made weak coffee this morning, or at least that's the excuse I'm going with. ;)

I have to do this ~15 million times, so the faster, the better.

Code snip:

```
my @letters = split //, $string;
my $type;
foreach my $letter ( @letters ) {
  if (! $type) {
    if ($letter =~ /^[A-Z]$/) {
      $type = 'a'
    }
    else {
      $type = 'd'
    }
    $string = $letter;
    next;
  }
  else {
    if ($type eq 'a') {
      if ($letter =~ /^[0-9]$/) {
        $string .= '-' . $letter;
        $type = 'd';
        next;
      }
      else {
        $sring .= $letter;
      }
    }
    else {
      if ($letter =~ /^[A-Z]$/) {
etc, etc.
```

Ugh, it hurts just looking at that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
$string =~ s/([A-Z])([0-9])/$1-$2/g;
$string =~ s/([0-9])([A-Z])/$1-$2/g;
```

Add the `/i` modifier if you want to to be case-insensitive.

---

Probably faster (since it avoids captures), but requires 5.10:

```
$string =~ s/[A-Z]\K(?=[0-9])/-/g;
$string =~ s/[0-9]\K(?=[A-Z])/-/g;
```

Comment: Argh! I did `$string =~ s/[^A-Z0-9]//g` to ensure the string was alphanumeric to begin with, I can't believe I didn't think of this. Cheers!

Comment: Added an optimization.